# How to display the pdf within web pages. Is there any javascript framework for the same?

Tags: html, pdf

I have pdf files which should be displayed within web pages(shouldn't be opened in separate window or tab )

Comment: this post could help you: [recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) library.

see demo:
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

GitHub:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PDF.js from mozilla.

[PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best approach is to use the [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library. It's a pure HTML5/JavaScript renderer for PDF documents without any third-party plugins.

Online demo: [http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js